# use of ORM with ODB in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite, odb

I am trying to use ODB to work with SQLite database in c++. I found the below code in [docs of ODB](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#2).
when I replaced MySQL with SQLite I got error as no instance of constructor when trying to create persistent person objects.
How can I make use of ODB with SQLite?

```
//

#include <memory>   // std::auto_ptr
#include <iostream>

#include <odb/database.hxx>
#include <odb/transaction.hxx>

#include <odb/mysql/database.hxx>

#include "person.hxx"
#include "person-odb.hxx"

using namespace std;
using namespace odb::core;

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    auto_ptr<database> db (new odb::mysql::database (argc, argv));

    unsigned long john_id, jane_id, joe_id;

    // Create a few persistent person objects.
    //
    {
      person john ("John", "Doe", 33);
      person jane ("Jane", "Doe", 32);
      person joe ("Joe", "Dirt", 30);

      transaction t (db->begin ());

      // Make objects persistent and save their ids for later use.
      //
      john_id = db->persist (john);
      jane_id = db->persist (jane);
      joe_id = db->persist (joe);

      t.commit ();
    }
  }
  catch (const odb::exception& e)
  {
    cerr << e.what () << endl;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: different databases are *different*.

Comment: From the docs you linked, "_To generate support code for the SQLite database you will need to pass the "--database sqlite" (or "-d sqlite") option to the ODB compiler. Your application will also need to link to the SQLite ODB runtime library (libodb-sqlite)._". Did you do this?

Comment: yes i did change mysql to sqlite `#include <odb/sqlite/database.hxx>`   `odb -d sqlite --generate-query --generate-schema person.hxx` . Also i have libodb-sqlite-2.4 and libodb-sqlite-dev installed. [odb_docs](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#2) . i am gettting redeclaration of class error but i am doing as per docs. `In file included from person-odb.hxx:16,
                 from driver.cxx:10:
person.hxx:10:7: error: redefinition of ‘class person’
   10 | class person`